# How to get a button to work with view in android

Tags: java, android, button, view, draw

I have been trying to add a erase function to this drawing app. I was planning on it just simpily drawing white over where you move your finger. For some reason  i cannot get the button to work. If i can get this button to work I will be able to add more colors ect.
(i have not done anything with Mainactivity)

```
package com.example.draw;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainDrawingView extends View
{
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private boolean erase;
private Path path = new Path();
Button aButton;

public MainDrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

    aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            erase = !erase;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if(erase) paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    else paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    // Get the coordinates of the touch event.
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Set a new starting point
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Connect the points
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    // Makes our view repaint and call onDraw

    invalidate();

    return true;
}
}
Activity_main<

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="#ffffff"

tools:context="com.example.draw.FullscreenActivity">



<!-- This is the view on which we will draw. -->

<view

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    class="com.example.draw.MainDrawingView"
    android:id="@+id/single_touch_view"

    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: if i delete aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            erase = !erase;
        }
    }); it will work fine but the button wont work(obviously)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your problem is that you're using the wrong types. Your `erase` variable is of type `Paint`:

```
private Paint erase = new Paint();
```

But in your code you're treating it like an `int` that represents a `boolean`.

```
if(erase != 0) { paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); }
if(erase == 0) { paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); }
...
erase = 1;
```

Secondly, you're never actually setting the `onClickListener` for your button.  Also, the logic to set the color should all be moved into either your `onTouch` or the `onClick` method.  You really should have:

```
public class MainDrawingView extends View
{
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private boolean erase;
    private Path path = new Path();
    Button aButton;

    public MainDrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                erase = !erase;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if(erase) paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        else paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        // Get the coordinates of the touch event.
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Set a new starting point
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // Connect the points
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        // Makes our view repaint and call onDraw

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: it almost worked but eclipse says at line public class MainDrawingView extends View implements onClick; that I need to create a interface onclick. How would i Do that?

Comment: Sorry you can remove that.  I'l update the answer

Comment: it still wont work. I will add the activity_main which might not work with the button press? it works fine with a button on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your view is not being created with the following constructor

```
Context context, AttributeSet attrs
```

It might be using a different default constructor that you have not overridden.  Then nothing would get setup and you would not get any click behavior that your expecting from your listener.

Comment: how would i check for that though??

Comment: @user3609407 If you were to cut your current constructor out, Eclipse should show a red box and provide suggested includes.  One of those or several of those might be what you need depending on how you are calling it.  That's a quick way, but another default is with just Context that you can override for example.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have your onCreate(Bundle savedInstances) method setup to to add the listener correctly.